# JPA javax.persistence.metamodel.ListAttribute

Tags: jpa, openjpa

I am running a JPA test and I keep getting the error at the end of this post.  I have no idea why I'm getting this error, however, I do not get this error when testing in JUnit.  I know this is probably a generic message and a broad question but if there's a simple answer, I would appreciate it.

Here are my 3 class files:

```
package menu.entity;

import static javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;

@IdClass(menu.entity.FeatureKey.class)
@Entity
@Table(name="FEATURES")
public class Feature implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="PROD_ID", 
        nullable = false, 
        insertable = false, 
        updatable = false,
        precision=22)
private BigDecimal prodId;

@Id
@Column(name="FEATURE", 
        nullable = false, 
        insertable = false, 
        updatable = false,
        precision=22)
private BigDecimal feature;

@Column(name="FEATURE_NAME", length=50)
private String featureName;

@Column(name="FEATURE_PATH", length=100)
private String featurePath;

@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="featureObj")
private List<Function> functions;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="PROD_ID", referencedColumnName="PROD_ID")
    })
private Product product;

public Feature() {
}

public BigDecimal getFeature() {
    return this.feature;
}

public void setFeature(BigDecimal feature) {
    this.feature = feature;
}

public String getFeatureName() {
    return this.featureName;
}

public void setFeatureName(String featureName) {
    this.featureName = featureName;
}

public String getFeaturePath() {
    return this.featurePath;
}

public void setFeaturePath(String featurePath) {
    this.featurePath = featurePath;
}

public BigDecimal getProdId() {
    return this.prodId;
}

public void setProdId(BigDecimal prodId) {
    this.prodId = prodId;
}

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public List<Function> getFunctions() {
    return functions;
}

public void setFunctions(List<Function> functions) {
    this.functions = functions;
}

}


package menu.entity;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.ListAttribute;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;

@Generated(value="Dali", date="2012-10-01T17:03:26.750-0400")
@StaticMetamodel(Feature.class)
public class Feature_ {
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Feature, BigDecimal> prodId;
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Feature, BigDecimal> feature;
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Feature, String> featureName;
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Feature, String> featurePath;
public static volatile ListAttribute<Feature, Function> functions;
public static volatile SingularAttribute<Feature, Product> product;
}


package menu.entity;

import static javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;


@IdClass(menu.entity.FunctionKey.class)
@Entity
@Table(name="FUNCTIONS")
public class Function implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="PROD_ID", 
        nullable = false, 
        insertable = false, 
        updatable = false,
        precision=22)
private BigDecimal prodId;

@Id
@Column(name="FEATURE", 
        nullable = false, 
        insertable = false, 
        updatable = false,
        precision=22)
private BigDecimal feature;

@Id
@Column(name="FUNC", 
        nullable = false, 
        insertable = false, 
        updatable = false,
        precision=22)
private BigDecimal func;

@Column(name="FUNC_NAME", length=50)
private String funcName;

@Column(name="FUNC_PATH", length=80)
private String funcPath;

@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="function")
private List<Task> tasks;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="PROD_ID", referencedColumnName="PROD_ID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="FEATURE", referencedColumnName="FEATURE")
    })
private Feature featureObj;

public Function() {
}

public BigDecimal getFeature() {
    return this.feature;
}

public void setFeature(BigDecimal feature) {
    this.feature = feature;
}

public BigDecimal getFunc() {
    return func;
}

public void setFunc(BigDecimal func) {
    this.func = func;
}

public String getFuncName() {
    return this.funcName;
}

public void setFuncName(String funcName) {
    this.funcName = funcName;
}

public String getFuncPath() {
    return this.funcPath;
}

public void setFuncPath(String funcPath) {
    this.funcPath = funcPath;
}

public BigDecimal getProdId() {
    return this.prodId;
}

public void setProdId(BigDecimal prodId) {
    this.prodId = prodId;
}

public Feature getFeatureObj() {
    return featureObj;
}

public void setFeatureObj(Feature featureObj) {
    this.featureObj = featureObj;
}

public List<Task> getTasks() {
    return tasks;
}

public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    this.tasks = tasks;
}

}
```

Regards,

Paul

Here is the full stack trace:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute "functions" of any not
>   found in menu.entity.Feature  at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AbstractManagedType.notFoundException(AbstractManagedType.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:461)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.populate(MetamodelImpl.java:311)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.instantiate(MetamodelImpl.java:257)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.find(MetamodelImpl.java:226)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.(MetamodelImpl.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getMetamodel(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:346)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:333)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerImpl.java:1649)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerImpl.java:101)
>     at menu.ejb.RequestBean.init(RequestBean.java:60)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invoke(WeldMethodImpl.java:174)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:398)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(ManagedBean.java:174)
>     at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:294)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:599)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:665)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:136)
>     at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:686)  at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:695)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1$1.proceed(ManagedBean.java:161)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1.work(ManagedBean.java:157)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$FixInjectionPoint.run(ManagedBean.java:131)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.inject(ManagedBean.java:153)
>     at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:293)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:103)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
>     at
>   menu.web.MenuManager$Proxy$_$$*WeldClientProxy.getMenuItemsS(MenuManager$Proxy$*$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)  at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)    at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)   at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Oct 2, 2012 12:50:22 PM
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy
>   handleRenderException SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/menu.xhtml]
>   javax.el.ELException: /menu.xhtml @26,51
>   value="#{menuManager.menuItemsS}": Error reading 'menuItemsS' on type
>   menu.web.MenuManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy    at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)   at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke
>   [method] @PostConstruct private menu.ejb.RequestBean.init() on
>   menu.ejb.RequestBean@19ca9ff  at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:400)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(ManagedBean.java:174)
>     at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:294)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:599)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:665)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:136)
>     at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:686)  at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:695)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1$1.proceed(ManagedBean.java:161)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1.work(ManagedBean.java:157)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$FixInjectionPoint.run(ManagedBean.java:131)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.inject(ManagedBean.java:153)
>     at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:293)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:103)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
>     at
>   menu.web.MenuManager$Proxy$_$$*WeldClientProxy.getMenuItemsS(MenuManager$Proxy$*$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)  at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.*getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)    at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     ... 34 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invoke(WeldMethodImpl.java:174)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:398)
>     ... 63 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: public static
>   volatile javax.persistence.metamodel.ListAttribute
>   menu.entity.Feature*.functions    at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.populate(MetamodelImpl.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.instantiate(MetamodelImpl.java:257)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.find(MetamodelImpl.java:226)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.(MetamodelImpl.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getMetamodel(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:346)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:333)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerImpl.java:1649)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerImpl.java:101)
>     at menu.ejb.RequestBean.init(RequestBean.java:60)   ... 73 more Oct 2,
>   2012 12:50:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with
>   path [/jsfCDITest] threw exception [WELD-000049 Unable to invoke
>   [method] @PostConstruct private menu.ejb.RequestBean.init() on
>   menu.ejb.RequestBean@19ca9ff] with root cause
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: public static volatile
>   javax.persistence.metamodel.ListAttribute
>   menu.entity.Feature_.functions    at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.populate(MetamodelImpl.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.instantiate(MetamodelImpl.java:257)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.find(MetamodelImpl.java:226)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.MetamodelImpl.(MetamodelImpl.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getMetamodel(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:346)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:333)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerImpl.java:1649)
>     at
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerImpl.java:101)
>     at menu.ejb.RequestBean.init(RequestBean.java:60)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invoke(WeldMethodImpl.java:174)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:398)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(ManagedBean.java:174)
>     at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:294)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:599)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:665)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:136)
>     at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:686)  at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:695)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1$1.proceed(ManagedBean.java:161)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1.work(ManagedBean.java:157)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$FixInjectionPoint.run(ManagedBean.java:131)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.inject(ManagedBean.java:153)
>     at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:293)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:103)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
>     at
>   menu.web.MenuManager$Proxy$_$$*WeldClientProxy.getMenuItemsS(MenuManager$Proxy$*$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)  at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)    at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)   at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
>     at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that RuntimeException is thrown because another exception occurred. That other exception's stack trace should be printed to the console.

Comment: I've posted the full stack trace but I'm uncertain where the true error is occurring.  The error happens before I even make a call to the EntityManager of my requesting class.

Comment: One additional note is that this error occurs when I call the entity manager getCriteriaBuilder().

Comment: The _real_ error seem to be the IllegalArgumentException: Attribute "functions" of any not found in menu.entity.Feature. OpenJPA seems to find the "Feature" type but not its "functions" attribute (i.e. the mapped field). I do not see anything obviously wrong with your code.... You said this error does not happen in your JUnit test - do you build a CriteriaBuilder in your test?

Comment: Yes, I do build a CriteriaBuilder in my test.

Comment: CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    Root<Product> product = cq.from(Product.class);
    cq.where(cb.equal(product.get("prodId"),prodId));
    Subquery<Permission> subquery = cq.subquery(Permission.class);      
    Root<Permission> subRootEntity = subquery.from(Permission.class);
    Predicate correlatePredicate =   cb.equal(subRootEntity.get("prodId"), product);
    subquery.where(correlatePredicate);
    cq.select(product);
    TypedQuery<Product> q = em.createQuery(cq);
    List<Product> allProducts = q.getResultList();

Comment: The only difference I can see is that for my Junit test, I call -javaagent:openjpa jar and with this JSF test, I'm just adding the openjpa jar to the web library of the project in eclipse.  I've seemed to narrow the problem down to the OneToMany and ManyToOne relationships of the entities.  When I comment these out, the code runs but of course will only return a Feature and no embedded Function list.

Comment: Hmmm - I can't claim to have any experience with OpenJPA at runtime. :-) But your problem sounds like maybe your entity classes are not being "enhanced" by OpenJPA when they are loaded? Sorry I'm reaching the limit of my helpfulness.... :-)

Comment: Brian, I appreciate you assistance.  I've used the OpenJPA eclipse plugin to enhance the classes created my class_ files.  I can get the program to run when I remove the OnToMany relationship.